# How to create a table relation in Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, orchardcms

I want the MachineRecord to contain a GroupRecord Id, like the following:

**MachineRecord**

Id
Name
Number
GroupRecord

**GroupRecord**

Id
Name

What I have tried:

I have tried to make the property in the model a
`public virtual GroupRecord GroupRecord { get; set; }`
and the database column name `GroupRecord_Id`, but somehow that won't work, tried some other ways like giving the property the name `GroupRecordId` and the table column `GroupRecord` and so on, but all with no results.

So the question is, how to get this to work so the MachineRecord table contains a GroupRecord Id?

*Machine.cs*

```
namespace PowerAll.Voorraad.Models
{
  public class MachineRecord
  {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int MachineNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description4 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description5 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description6 { get; set; }
    public virtual string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupRecord GroupRecord { get; set; }
    public virtual char PriceType { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int Year { get; set; }
  }
}
```

*Group.cs*

```
namespace PowerAll.Voorraad.Models
{
  public class GroupRecord
  {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string GroupName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

*Migrations.cs*

```
namespace PowerAll.Voorraad
{
  public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl
  {
    public int Create()
    {
      SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("GroupRecord", table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column<string>("GroupName", column => column.WithLength(100))
      );

      SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MachineRecord", table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column<int>("MachineNumber", column => column.NotNull())
        .Column<string>("Title", column => column.NotNull().WithLength(40))
        .Column<string>("Description1", column => column.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description2", column => column.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description3", column => column.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description4", column => column.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description5", column => column.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description6", column => column.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("SerialNumber", column => column.WithLength(20))
        .Column<int>("GroupRecord_id", column => column.NotNull())
        .Column<char>("PriceType", column => column.NotNull().WithLength(1))
        .Column<decimal>("Price", column => column.NotNull())
        .Column<int>("Year", column => column.WithLength(4))
      );

      // Return the version that this feature will be after this method completes
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

*MachineController.cs*

```
namespace PowerAll.Voorraad.Controllers
{
  [Themed]
  public class MachineController : Controller
  {
    private readonly IRepository<MachineRecord> machineRecords;

    public MachineController(IRepository<MachineRecord> MachineRecords) {
        machineRecords = MachineRecords;
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        var items = machineRecords.Table;

        return View(items);
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I came this far thanks to endorphin, but when I try to execute `AddDummyData()` I get this error: `could not insert: [PowerAll.Voorraad.Models.MachineRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO PowerAll_Voorraad_MachineRecord (MachineNumber, Title, Description1, Description2, Description3, Description4, Description5, Description6, SerialNumber, PriceType, Price, Year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]` While when I step trough the code all values are being posted right.

This is my AddDummyData():

```
public void AddDummyData()
{
  var GroupRecord = new GroupRecord { GroupName = "Oldtimers" };

  groupRecords.Create(GroupRecord);

  var MachineRecord = new MachineRecord
  {
    MachineNumber = 100001,
    Title = "Landini L25",
    Description1 = "Desc 1",
    Description2 = "Desc 2",
    Description3 = "Desc 3",
    Description4 = "Desc 4",
    Description5 = "Desc 5",
    Description6 = "Desc 6",
    SerialNumber = "100000",
    GroupRecord = GroupRecord,
    PriceType = 'I',
    Price = 7999.99m,
    Year = 1954
  };

  machineRecords.Create(MachineRecord);
}
```

EDIT 3:

Now it's working, this is my working code (for those who are struggling on this too)

*Migrations.cs*

```
  public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl
  {
    public int Create()
    {
      SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MachineRecord", table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column<int>("GroupRecord_Id")
        .Column<int>("MachineNumber", column => column.NotNull())
        .Column<string>("Title", column => column.NotNull().WithLength(40))
        .Column<string>("Description", column => column.WithLength(70))
        .Column<char>("PriceType", column => column.NotNull().WithLength(1))
        .Column<decimal>("Price", column => column.NotNull())
        .Column<int>("Year", column => column.WithLength(4))
      );

      SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("GroupRecord", table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column<string>("Name")
      );

      return 1;
    }
  }
```

*MachineRecord.cs*

```
  public class MachineRecord
  {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int MachineNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupRecord GroupRecord { get; set; }
    public virtual char PriceType { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int Year { get; set; }
  }
```

*GroupRecord.cs*

```
  public class GroupRecord
  {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to your problem is split across how you structure the models and how you define their relationship in the Migrations.cs.

Here is a solution that I have used in the past.

Firstly, the class which contains the link to the second class.

```
public class CaptureRecord : ContentPartRecord {
   public virtual string CaptureName { get; set; }
   public virtual OptionsRecord OptionsRecord { get; set; }   
}
```

Note: inheriting from `ContentPartRecord` gives you an ID.

Then the second class (in this case I do not need to inherit from `ContentPartRecord` so I add the ID myself)

```
public class OptionsRecord {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the Migrations.cs add the OptionRecord ID in the CaptureRecord table definition

```
public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl
{
    SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("CaptureRecord",
            table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column<string>("CaptureName")
            .Column<int>("OptionsRecord_id");

    SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("OptionsRecord",
            table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<string>("Name"));

    return 1;
}
```

Hopefully this will give you a push in the right direction in terms of how to structure the relationship between your two tables.

Edit: To add content to this sort of structure you will need to manually manage this yourself using the `IRepository` instances.

So in your controller `AddDummyData` gives an example of this.

```
 public class MachineController : Controller {
   private readonly IRepository<MachineRecord> _machineRecords;
   private readonly IRepository<GroupRecord> _groupRecords;

   public MachineController(IRepository<MachineRecord> machineRecords, IRepository<GroupRecord> groupRecords) {
     _machineRecords = machineRecords;
     _groupRecords = groupRecords;
   }

   public void AddDummyData(){
     // create a grouprecord in the database
     _groupRecords.Create(new GroupRecord { Id = 1, GroupName = "One" });

     // get the groupRecord just created (annoying that Create doesnt return the instance, 
     // but I dont know a way around this
     var groupRecord = _groupRecords
        .Fetch(x => x.Id == 1)
        .Single();

     // create a machine return with the grouprecord assigned to the GroupRecord property 
     _machineRecords.Create(new MachineRecord { 
        Id = 1,
        ..
        GroupRecord = groupRecord
     });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is exactly how I did it, but I think the problem is that I don't inherit any model from ContentPartRecord, because I don't need that. I just made the classes the same as your OptionsRecord class, I added an Id myself. Could this be the problem? Is there any way to do this without inheriting from ContentPartRecord?

Comment: Inheriting from ContentPartRecord shouldn't matter as long as you add your own ID and make it a primary key, identity, etc. What is the error your actually getting from Orchard to know that it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't get any errors from Orchard, and if I use breakpoint en check results view GroupRecord's value is NULL. (Yes, I added a group with that Id in the db :) ). I will post my code in the question in a minute. thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Do you have any functionality to add a MachineRecord which links to a GroupRecord? Because with the code you have added the GroupRecord property of the MachineRecord will be null.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you well, but no, this is all I got right now, but when I manually add an row to the GroupRecord table in the db, with Id 1 and add a row to the MachineRecord table with GroupRecord_id 1, it should give the group, right? Thanks so far.

Comment: Sadly enough still not working I added the code in my question, this is gonna be a long, long question! :) Really appreciate it that you spend so much time answering my question!

Comment: Tried it again after some time, now it is working! don't know what I did wrong exactly, but @endorphin, thank you very much for you help! Really appreciate it how much time is being spend on this community to help others.